# Inserting/Deleting multiple entries for each checked checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently I have multiple checkboxes that the user can check or uncheck. The checked values should make a new entry in the database and the unchecked values that were checked before should be deleted from the database. As of now my code displays as checked for all the entries that are currently there in my database, but if I check new values and submit, those values dont get added to my database and same with deletion. This is my current code:

```
<h4 class="text-uppercase w-100 px-4">Featured Amenities</h4>

<?php $checked = array();
    foreach($checked_facility as $key => $value){ 
    $checked[]=$value['facilities_id'];
    }
    if($facilities) foreach($facilities as $facility):  ?>
    <fieldset id="availablenetworked">
        <input type="checkbox" <?php echo in_array($facility['id'], $checked) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> name="facility[]" id="<?php echo $facility['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $facility['id'] ?>"> 
        <label for="<?php echo $facility['id'] ?>"><span id="<?php echo $facility['id'] ?>-am-desc"><?php echo $facility['title'] ?></span></label>
    </fieldset>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Controller Class:

```
if ($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('facility')) != '') {
    $facilityPost = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('facility'));
    $facilityArray = array();
    $c = 0;
    foreach($facilityPost as $fp){
        if ($fp != ''){
        $facilityArray[$c]['listings_id']= $id;
        $facilityArray[$c]['facilities_id']= $fp;

        $c++;
    }
}

    if(count($facilityArray) > 0){
        $this->listings_model->save_facility($facilityArray);
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
function save_facility($maindata){
    $this->db->insert_batch("crm_property_facilities",$maindata); 
    return $this->db->insert_id(); 
}
```

Now I did add a `var_dump($this->input->post('facility')); die();` after the submit to check the data and it return NULL. So not quiet sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: I love your line:  `$c++;`

Comment: what about dumping $_POST?

Comment: If POST return NULL, somehow all the code doesnt t link to each other